# Adding scrollbars to table when it overflows after adding new items in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a simple web app with bootstrap mainly for learning purposes.

I have created the main layout with css grid instead of using bootstrap grid system. One of the reasons for this is that when I finish the webapp I will electronize it to have a little desktop tool and I want it to always cover all viewport. I don't want to have scrollbars in the top part of the webapp (body).

This is the simple css grid layout. The idea is to create something like a file manager with a column and two rows. In the top row I will show the files in current folder and in the bottom row a transfer queue where user can add files and folders to current path:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
  border-style: none;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.device-folders {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.queue-contents {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<header>

</header>

<body>
  <div class="top-layout">
    <div class="device-folders d-flex flex-column border border-success">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row border border-primary">
        <div>
          <img src="/assets/icons/arrow-left-circle.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" title="Bootstrap">
        </div>
        <div class="ml-auto">
          <img src="/assets/icons/folder-plus.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" title="Bootstrap">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-row flex-grow-1 bg-warning overflow-auto">
        <table class="table table-sm border border-danger max-heigth:200px">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">File</th>
              <th scope="col">Size</th>
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Type</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="queue-contents border border-danger">
      <div class="container h-100 p-2">
        <div class="align-items-center justify-content-center d-flex flex-column h-100">
          <img class="" src="/assets/icons/file-earmark-image.svg" width="50em" />
          <h1 class="text-muted ">Drag Files to transfer</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The result is something like this:

[image]

The problem is that when I add new items to the table that is inside the top row and makes the table frow, it "eats" part of the are where files must be dragged to be transfered. And this is something I don't quite understand because the top row is constrained to a 66% size and the bottom one to a 33% by the grid template columns and rows. I thought that these were hard edges and no children could be rendered outside them.

What can I do to avoid this?

Edit: I have tried to move the overflow-auto in the div containing the table to the div just below the top-layout div. And this did work (more or less). I can see a scrollbar when the top row (the one that will show the files) needs more space to grow because I add new elements. The problem is that everything is scrolled. The table and the button bar. And I want the button bar to be fixed.

Comment: I see no overflow rule applied to the table container. Try to specifically state an overflow rule to `.device-folders`

Comment: Just before you answered I did that. You can see my Edit to see what happened. Mainly that now all scrolls. The table and and button bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it in the snippet here and it works as intended. Unless a specific overflow rule has been declared, the overflow will happen for the body. I just added `.device-fodlers { overflow: auto; }` and as you see the scrollbar only appears for the top 2/3 container.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
  border-style: none;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.device-folders {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  overflow: auto;
}

.queue-contents {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<header>

</header>

<body>
  <div class="top-layout">
    <div class="device-folders d-flex flex-column border border-success">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row border border-primary">
        <div>
          <img src="/assets/icons/arrow-left-circle.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" title="Bootstrap">
        </div>
        <div class="ml-auto">
          <img src="/assets/icons/folder-plus.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" title="Bootstrap">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-row flex-grow-1 bg-warning overflow-auto">
        <table class="table table-sm border border-danger max-heigth:200px">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">File</th>
              <th scope="col">Size</th>
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Type</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="queue-contents border border-danger">
      <div class="container h-100 p-2">
        <div class="align-items-center justify-content-center d-flex flex-column h-100">
          <img class="" src="/assets/icons/file-earmark-image.svg" width="50em" />
          <h1 class="text-muted ">Drag Files to transfer</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain why it works? I understand why you use overflow-auto but not why you use it ad .device-folders and in the div just before the table definition. Why isn't the button bar at the top scrolling? Any good read to undertand the nested use of overflow-auto?

Comment: the default behavior is, to scroll the entire website (body) unless an overflow-rul has been declared to a child. `.device-folder` is the direct child of the css-grid container with a preset hight of `100vh`. so if the content is larger, your css-grid container will start to overflow and add the scrollbar, however the scrollbar will be added to the container means it will influence both childs. therefor the child `.device-folder` must get an overflow rule to let the child overflow instead of the container.